# Get computation cost of running a tensorflow graph

Tags: c++, tensorflow, xla

I have a frozen tensorflow graph, and I'm wondering what the best method is to get the computation cost of running it(assuming it only uses deterministic operations and nothing that makes it turing complete like while loops).

Is there a way to run a static graph analysis to get either the worst case or the average case computation cost? I'm not sure what metric I should use, a possible metric is number of instructions.

Comment: Warning "best" is fuzzy at the best of times.

Comment: I guess I'm more looking for a way to go forward. It's a hard to define problem, but I essentially want a way to get the cost of a graph without knowing the inputs, and knowing that the graph is deterministic.